# Image control doesn't get rendered

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a WPF application with multiple small editors. One of these editors requires to load two images, enter a name in a TextBox and hit a save button.

In the code this does work flawless. The files are saved in a model and the image can be loaded. Before hitting the save button both of the images are actually shown in the editor. However after reopening (for editing) only one image is rendered.

I tested a bit around and found out that always the first image doesn't get rendered while the second does.

For example in the XAML it looks like this:

```
<Image Name="BackgroundImage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=Background}" Width="120" Height="90"/>
<Image Name="ForegroundImage" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=Foreground}" Width="120" Height="90"/>
```

Here **BackgroundImage** doesn't get rendered, even though the property **Background** of the model has loaded the image successfully. If I were to swap these XAML Tags, meaning putting the **ForegroundImage** control above the **BackgroundImage**, then **ForegroundImage** doesn't get rendered while **BackgroundImage** does. Even if I don't change anything else like the Grid.Row or Column.

Then I tried to load the images in the code behind in the Loaded event handler of the window:

```
private void LocationEditor_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundImage.Source = ((Location)DataContext).Background;
    ForegroundImage.Source = ((Location)DataContext).Foreground;
}
```

The same applies to this situation. Whichever line is executed first, won't be rendered in the Window.

In case it'll help, here's the code of the **Background** property (**Foreground** is built the same):

```
[JsonIgnore]
public BitmapImage Background
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BackgroundFile))
        {
            SetFree();
            SetImage();
        }
        else
            _background = null;
        return _background;
    }
}
```

The **SetFree()** method frees up memory resources if the image isn't needed anymore. This occurs when the window closes or whenever the **BitmapImage** is needed. (It'll reload the image each time in case the file of the image has changed.)

The **SetImage()** method does just one simple thing: Loading the image of the **BackgroundFile** image file and saves it in the **_background** field.

---

I don't quite know what the problem could be. I've tried out a few things but I don't work often with images while coding.

Comment: Can you provide more xaml code? What controls are the images in? One tool that might help you is a visual tree inspector like Snoop which you can use to view UI elements and their values in real time.

Comment: @user2619824 The controls are just in a Grid which has no extra parameters. And that grid is a direct child of the window. So nothing fancy there. I'll check out Snoop. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Your view model property implementations are looking odd. Please show us the SetFree and SetImage methods. How do these methods know whether it's the Background or the Foreground property?

Comment: Besides that, did you try to bind directly to the BackgroundFile path, like `<Image Source="{Binding BackgroundFile}"/>`? This should also work, because there is built-in type conversion.

Comment: @Clemens 2 I didn't know it can convert automatically to an image. I tried binding it directly to the file path and....it works. I suppose I somehow made a mistake with the SetFree method, though I still don't know why it "technically" works for the second image. Maybe submit it as answer? It was what helped me after all.

Comment: I also assume there is something wrong with the SetFree method. However, since you haven't shown it, it's hard to tell what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your `SetFree()` or `SetImage()` methods.

Fortunately you don't need the `Background` and `Foreground` properties in your view model at all, because WPF provides built-in automatic type conversion from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to `ImageSource`. You can hence directly bind the Image's Source properties to the appropriate path properties in the view model:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding BackgroundFile}"/>
<Image ... Source="{Binding ForegroundFile}"/>
```

---

For completeness, if you still wanted to have these properties, i'd suggest a simple implementation like shown below. Built-in image caching will take care that the file is not decoded more often than necessary:

```
public ImageSource Background
{
    get
    {
        if (BackgroundFile != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri(BackgroundFile));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```